# Refactoring Rails Join Tables – Which format should I keep

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

I am currently refactoring tables used in a Rails application. Throughout the development people have used various different methods for creating join tables to be used in `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Which of these three formats should I use;

### 1 – ID and Time Details

id, table_a_id, table_b_id, created_at, updated_at

### 2 – ID

id, table_a_id, table_b_id

### 3 – Just the table IDs

table_a_id, table_b_id

### Current Thinking

I am leaning towards the third option since nowhere in my application do we care about when a relationship was made, nor do I see the point in an ID since we will never be querying that table directly.

Is this short sighted? The overhead is going to be minimal in including all the fields, but if they are just going to sit there not being used I would rather we didn't have them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, then your third option is the best choice. A HABTM association table shouldn't contain any other data besides just the foreign keys of the referenced rows.

Otherwise, if you do want to include any kind of relational data between the two tables, you would use `has_many :through` for your rails association.

Additional resources for reference:

- [Rails Docs - has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)
- [Rails Docs - has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Comment: Great stuff, we are using HABTM throughout the app so this makes a lot of sense.